# redirect command output with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I need redirect output to file and add datetime.
I try this:

```
make all | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' > file
```

I expect:

```
2011-12-13 15:00:50 compilation....

2011-12-13 15:00:52 still compilation

2011-12-13 15:00:55 compilation

...
```

How can I do this? If i remove "> file" on the screen i seen correct output. But I will redirect this to file.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: have you tried redirect WITH awk? like` awk '....print "yourStuff" > file'`

Comment: Yes, I tried, but this solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `tee` command like this:

```
make all | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' | tee file
```

tee will display output on STDOUT and store the output in file as well.